# JavaScript regular expressions in re-builder

Tags: regular-expressions

Is there any package that allows me to input regular expressions following the JavaScript syntax (or even Perl Compatible Reg. Exp.)?

I want to have an interactive regular expression builder (like re-builder), but using standard syntaxes rather than the clumsy default syntax in emacs.

Comment: None that I know of, but you could simply run JavaScript or Perl interpreter in Emacs to test your regular expression.  Just saying, in case that wasn't obvious.